# Selecionar imagem - envio phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Pessoal estou tentando enviar um e-mail pelo phpmailer com uma imagem de assinatura no final, no caso eu tenho este select para selecionar a assinatura desejada.

```
                        <select class="form-control" id="assinatura" name="assinatura">
                            <option value="">Seleciona uma opção</option>
                            <option value="suporte">Suporte</option>
                            <option value="alan">Alan</option>
                            <option value="ricardo">Ricardo</option>
                            <option value="rogerio">Rogerio</option>
                            <option value="gislei">Gislei</option>
                        </select>
```

E este é o codigo no phpmailer, ele nao envia a imagem no final.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>E-mail</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
            </head>
            <body>

            <?php
                date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

        require_once('./phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php'); 
        require './phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        //variaveis - para envio


        $sistema            = $_POST['sistema'];
        $email_smart        = $_POST['email'];
        $senha_smart        = $_POST['senha'];
        $remetent_smart     = $_POST['remetent'];
        $nome_destinatario  = $_POST['nome_destinatario'];
        $destinatario       = $_POST['destinatario'];
        $assunto            = $_POST['assunto'];
        $mensagem           = $_POST['editor1'];
        $arquivo            = $_FILES['arquivo'];
        $assinatura         = $_POST['assinatura'];


        if($assinatura == 'suporte'){
            $img_assinatura = ("<img src'http://www.meusite.com.br/email/img/assinaturas/ass1.jpg'>");
        } else {
            echo "assinatura não selecionado";
        }
        }

        $template = str_replace('%assinatura%', $img_assinatura, $template);
        $template = str_replace('%mensagem%', $mensagem, $template);

        //inicio PHPMailer
        $mail = new PHPMailer; // instancia a classe PHPMailer

        $mail->IsSMTP();

        //configuração do usuário do email
        $mail->Host         = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure   = "ssl"; 
        $mail->Port         = '465';
        $mail->Username     = $email;
        $mail->Password     = $senha;

        //remetente
        $mail->From = $email; 
        $mail->FromName = $remetent; 

        //destinatrio
        $mail->AddAddress($destinatario);

        //enviar a mensagem com anexo
        $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
        $mail->Subject = $assunto; 
        $mail->MsgHTML($template);
        $mail->AddAttachment($arquivo['tmp_name'], $arquivo['name']  );

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";   
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";  



        // Controle de erro ou sucesso no envio
        if (!$mail->Send())
        {
             echo "Erro de envio: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
         }
        else{

            echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!";
        }
        ?>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente não aparece porque ele reconhece o Body como texto e não como HTML. Na configuração do PHPMailer, antes de enviar a mensagem (`$mail->Send()`) adicione a linha:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Isso deve resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver desta forma.

```
if($assinatura == 'suporte'){
$img_assinatura = "./img/assinaturas/suporte.jpg";
} else {
echo "assinatura não selecionado";
}
```

e no template coloquei assim para substituir somente o caminho.

```
 <img src="%assinatura%" align="center" style="display: block;" alt="">
```